# can i delete a sharepoint timer job while it is running? and if yes what happens with the function when interrumped?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, timer

can i delete a sharepoint timer job while it is running? and if yes what happens with the function when interrumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

The function does not get interrupted.  It either finishes or is oprhaned and cannot report back status.

Answer (score 0):

Of course,

But several times, with me, happened in central admin at timer job status page the shown table appears the same custom timer jobs repeated.

For this do not happen, make sure you disabled it (timer job) before uninstall.

Cheers